# Storing integer in char buffer array becomes binary value

Tags: c

I have an array of integers, for example:

I `memcpy` the value into a char buffer, and the next time I retrieve it, it becomes a binary value, for example, `00000` -> `16`. How do I avoid this?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int outgoingPorts[4] = { 100000, 100001, 100002, 100003 };
memcpy(buf, &outgoingPorts[0], sizeof(outgoingPorts[0]);

printf("Port no: %i\n", buf);
```

Here, `buf` or the first outgoing port is `16` instead of `10000`.

Comment: Did you mean: `sizeof outgoingPorts`. Secondly what did you expect in output?

Comment: "How do I avoid this?" - avoid *what*? What is this code *supposed* to be doing? (Ie. what are you *trying* to accomplish)? You copied the byte-representation of an `int` into a char array. What did you *hope* this would accomplish?

Comment: I meant to just put the first element of outgoingPorts so in this case, that is fine. And I'm expecting the output to be 10000

Comment: @WhozCraig I also plan on using the array to hold other chars, just not represented in my code. Is it possible to use a char array to hold both chars and ints while maintaining the decimal representation of an int? (not bytes)

Comment: Sending the base address of an array of `char` to `printf` with a `%i` format specifier certainly isn't the way to do that. Are you trying to put the *text* representation of the `int` value `10000` in the `char` buffer? I.e. `buf[0] = '1', buf[1] ='0'`, etc. ? Note those are characters. If so, it can be done using numerous tools (a `sprintf` function in C or C++, a `std::ostringstream`intermediary in C++, etc.).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes that's one option for me, putting the text representation and later on I can convert it to int values.

Comment: It is still not clear what the end purpose is. It first glance this looks like serialization to send data over some bus byte by byte... is which case converting to string certainly doesn't make any sense what-so-ever. And in that case you really should use `uint8_t` and not `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're using wrong format specifier altogether, for the content of a `char` pointer to be printed, you need to use `%s`, provided that `char` array in null-terminated. Otherwise, you'll face undefined behaviour.

Then, if you really want to store an `int` value in a `char` array, the most suited way to go is to make use of [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to *print* that value in the `char` array. Maybe the following pseudo-code will help you

```
char carr[16];
snprintf(carr, 16, "%d", outgoingPorts[0]);
printf("%s\n", carr);                         //should print 100000
```

FWIW, using wrong or mismatched format specifier invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I tried the same program with memcpy and it is not giving me any o/p can you tell me why Here is the code ... 

` #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // memcpy
#include <stdlib.h> //realloc
#define BUFSIZE 20

int main() {
 
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int outgoingPorts[4] = { 100000, 100001, 100002, 100003 };

memcpy(buf, &outgoingPorts, sizeof(outgoingPorts[0]));

printf("Port no: %i \n", buf);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @yanivx Remember, here, the representation matters. In my code, I've used _lexicographical_ way. `memcpy()` will copy the byte-representation, not the lexicographical value.

Comment: @yanivx 1) don't put code in comments, full markdown is not enabled and it's near-impossible to read. 2) just by changing the argument to `memcpy()` you cannot achieve this.

Comment: Sorry @Sourav Will keep this in mind in future regarding pasting the code. To conclude whenever we copy an int array to a char array to retain the values we should not use `memcpy` so that we don't copy the byte-representation.

Comment: @yanivx It's ok. And , NO, that is not a thumb rule, rather depends on your requirement, if you want an `int` value to be _printed_ __as__ a `char` array (or _string_), then you don't do `memcpy()`. In some case, if the byte-representation is required, you can use `memcpy()`, but that's not what you do in _this_case.